# JSP Website Deployment Query for Sub Domain

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, subdomain

Thanks in advance.

I have a question with regards to Sub-Domain.

the Primary domain is www.abc.com
There is a function in JSP which creates an Image for the user as membership cards which needs to be saved and which is also getting saved in a particular folder.
The concern is that whenever I make any changes on the websites java class files I re-upload the .war file on the server which recreates all the folders and files on the server in turn what happens is that all the Images created for the user also gets deleted.

So if I create a Sub-Domain called www.members.abc.com and create a folder in it where all the created Images will be stored then when I reupload the .war file will this sub-domain and its folders get affected.

Comment: You dont need a subdomain, just store the files anywhere (maybe /var/media/...) on your server and not inside the web archive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stefan.Are you trying to say that the Images folder should be outside the Root Folder and if Yes then how do I access those Images.